# Java process consuming 90% of swap space

Tags: jvm, tomcat7, swap

I have an application that has an allocated heap memory of 20GB. But even though the Heap memory is barely or less than 50% used, my server swap space gets used up totally. Java is the process that is consuming 90% of the swap.

The swap gets released only after restarting the application with a below warning. Looking for finding out the root cause and any impact due to this. Will my app fail to start if the swap is filled?

**Warning i see during App startup in logs**:

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>    Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 17895718912 bytes for committing reserved memory.. Out of swap space or heap resource limit exceeded (check with limits or ulimit)?
>    An error report with more information is generated,
>    it is saved as a file at this location:
>    /XX/myapp/apache-tomcat-7.0.90/bin/hs_err_pid86282.log
>   2020-01-14T05:17:18.742+0100 [INFO] [o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] Bean '(inner bean)#1814a032' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   ***Warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000003fjgh0000, 17895718912, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
>    There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>    Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 17895718912 bytes for committing reserved memory.. Out of 
>    swap space or heap resource limit exceeded (check with limits or ulimit)?
>    An error report with more information is generated,
>    it is saved as a file at this location:

**My JVM properties**:

```
/XX/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/XX/myapp/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -javaagent:/xx/myapp/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /XX/myapp/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/XX/myapp/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/XX/myapp/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/XX/myapp/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/XX/myapp/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Swap usage when checked for each process, its Java that uses 90% of Swap

Comment: *non-heap* memory, i.e. native I/O buffers… Further, you can’t say that only 50% of the heap is used, when you use `-Xms20g -Xmx20g` and `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`, as these options precisely request to make the 20g heap to look like being 100% used for the operating system.

Comment: How much memory do you have on the machine? How do you measure actual memory/swap consumption? Can you post the results of such measurements? Did you try to monitor the heap usage with JDK tools like jstat, jmap, jcmd or even a profiler?

Comment: Thank you guys. I monitor the JVM using Newrelic and can see that Heap used is <50%. I agree with Holger that -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch will make OS feel like 100% of 20Gb is used.

Further i have 28GB of RAM

`[root@vmB0810401 ~]# free -m

                   total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          28123       22021         562          92        5539        5546
Swap:          2047         272        1775`

I do not understand why SWAP is used when there is Free memory. And that being the Java application is another concern

Answer (score 3):

Your Java process is made *not* only from heap memory, watch [this for a good example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c755fFv1Rnk&t=2486s).

Now, you say that you have `28GB` of RAM, out of which you allocate `20GB` for heap *only*. Not only do you reserve virtual memory, but you also *commit* it, via `AlwaysPreTouch` (I now doubt you even understand what this does). So your OS, maps `20GB` of RAM to your process (simplified explanation).

Even if you see that only `50%` is occupied, the garbage collector that you use - does *not* release memory back to the OS, so the entire `20GC` are *always* occupied and can not be re-used by some other process. As such, it is pointless to measure or monitor the heap.

Your process fails with `Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map...`, as said this is unrelated to the heap. It fails in *native memory*, this is `!=` heap. I also do not know the specifics of your application, but `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` might not be a good option; instead you might enable the concurrent invocation (if your GC supports that) via `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent`.

You also seem to be using `CMS` garbage collector - which is deprecated.